# Load Table in SAS to Netezza

Tags: sas, netezza

I have this function that is supposed to create and load a table in Netezza.

```
proc sql;
connect to odbc as nzCon (noprompt="Driver={NetezzaSQL}; server=actual_server; port=5486; database=myDB; username=xxxx; password=xxxx;");

create table results as select *  from connection to nzCon 

(SELECT * FROM SASTable WHERE ADDRESS LIKE '2%');

disconnect from nzCon;
quit;
```

This is just creating the table in SAS because when I refresh my database in Netezza there are not tables created. How would I modify this so that it loads the table in Netezza?

Thanks!

Comment: When you use SQL pass through you cannot access both your SAS tables and data on the server. The code is literally passed to the server as is.

Comment: @Reeza so what you're saying is just because I can connect to the netezza server, it doesn't mean i can load data into a table on the server? Why is it so simple to extract information from netezza instead of loading information into it

Comment: It is easy, it's 'difficult' in your case because you're pass through. If you connect via a libname it's the same as using SAS data sets, at least code wise. Pass Through is really only useful to speed up a query when you have issues, if your column or table names are longer than 32 chars or you want to run something directly on the server and don't want to convert your code to SAS but use Netezza SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you can do move SAS dataset to Netezza by using libname statement.  @Reeza is trying to say you can find SAS datasets on netezza server. Bulkload =yes dataset option loads data in bulk into Netezza table instead of row by row.

```
  libname net_lib netezza server=actual_server; port=5486; database=myDB; username=xxxx; password=xxxx;";


    proc sql;
  create table net_lib.results
  (bulkload=YES) 
   as SELECT * FROM SASTable WHERE ADDRESS LIKE '2%';
 quit;
```

Comment: I get the error: `The Netezza Engine cannot be found` ...is this because I don't have SAS/ACCESS interface to Netezza? http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/acreldb/63647/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003163447.htm

Comment: try running  proc setinit; run;  then check whether you have SAS/ACCESS interface to Netezza

Comment: it seems like I don't have access to it. I'll see if I can get it and try it out. Thanks!

Comment: You can also usually connect via ODBC.

Comment: @Reeza can you provide an example with connecting via ODBC to load to Netezza?

Comment: @Reeza when you said connect via ODBC, you mean like how I do in my original post?

Comment: @Jim, no, that's not what I meant. You can use a libname with the ODBC connection to connect to netezza, assuming it supports odbc connections.